Issue with Application Visualization in Revit
I developed an application using C# based on Revit. When I run the application from Visual Studio, it works perfectly. However, when I run the app from Revit, all the functionalities work except for the visualization function. It works the first time and then crashes.
Is there anyone who can help me?
Is there anyone I can share the code with who can help me fix this bug?

Are you able to share some code and show exactly what is not working?
